# Difference between 'high in vhdl and $high in verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog, eda, research, basic-language

Is there any difference between 'high in vhdl  and $high in verilog??

Comment: Generally speaking, yes - both return the highest index possible. But maybe a more specific question would yield a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is `$high` in Verilog can only return a `integer` type whereas the `'high` attribute in VHDL returns the largest value in the type of the range.